# Constructing a 2d probability distribution function

Tags: statistics

I am working to categorize galaxies based on their color and intrinsic brightness, and I want to construct an empirical probability distribution function that describes what fraction of galaxies have some brightness (magnitude), and some color.

I have already constructed functions that describe the mean color at a certain magnitude, the width of the color distribution at a certain magnitude (standard deviation), and the number of counts at the peak value at a certain magnitude.  That is, I have mean as a function of brightness, st dev as a function of brightness, and total counts as a function of brightness.

From this, is there an easy way to construct a function that describes the number of galaxies as a function of both color and brightness?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, but you will have to find a model distribution for the color of galaxies. Conceivably, the general form of color distribution will be the same for every magnitude, only the parameters (mean, std, total count) will change.

For example, assume normal distribution of color at every magnitude. If there are $N_m$ galaxies of magnitude $m$, and the total number of galaxies is $N$, then the 2D distribution will have the density function 
$$f(c,m)  = \frac{N_m}{N} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma_m} \exp\left(-\frac{(c-c_m)^2}{2\sigma_m^2}\right) $$
So, you take the pdf for each $m$, multiply it by $N_m/N$, and put them together into a function of two variables. Note that $c$ is a continuous variable while $m$ is discrete. You could also discretize color values and fit them to some discrete distribution, such as binomial.

To find an appropriate distribution for color, you may want to experiment with some distribution fitting tool, such as the one in [Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/dfittool.html).